# Out Of Range exception when initializing binded DataGridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have my table from MS SQL Server 2012 binded through dataset to listbox, which is set as datsource to my dataGridView, now, I don't want to argue about merits or downsides of this solution but when I am initializating my dataGridView I get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

there is the code

```
public void initializeCarsGrid()
        {
             DataGridViewColumn column0 = carsGrid.Columns[0];
             column0.HeaderText = "Name";
             DataGridViewColumn column1 = carsGrid.Columns[1];
             column1.HeaderText = "Class";
             DataGridViewColumn column2 = carsGrid.Columns[2];
             column2.HeaderText = "Price / Day";
             DataGridViewColumn column3 = carsGrid.Columns[3];
             column3.HeaderText = "Capacity";
             DataGridViewColumn column4 = carsGrid.Columns[4];
             column4.HeaderText = "Registration number";
             DataGridViewColumn column5 = carsGrid.Columns[5];
             column5.HeaderText = "Description";

            carsGrid.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "@Name";
            carsGrid.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "@Class";
            carsGrid.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "@PricePerDay";
            carsGrid.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "@Capacity";
            carsGrid.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "@RegistrationNumber";
            carsGrid.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "@Description";

            selectCars();
        }
```

Here is whole code on pastebin

http://pastebin.com/b7vBhDZs

Comment: You are missing  `Column[4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the grid by using a dataset.
all you need to do is declare a dataset Get the values to the dataset and bind the datasource of the grid to the dataset
Something like this :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = SelectCars();
carsGrid.DataSource = ds;
carsGrid.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: Wow, that really solved the problem - I had this datsourced through bindinglist, but this did much better job. Now I have to figure out, how to display only some columns in my datagridview

Answer (score 3):

Probably this line causing the error

```
carsGrid.Columns[6];
```

I think you have only 6 columns in `carsGrid` but here you are accessing the 7th column value. You also missed it from the above code where you are setting the header text.

You might want to do this.

```
DataGridViewColumn column4 = carsGrid.Columns[4];
column4.HeaderText = "Registration number";
DataGridViewColumn column5 = carsGrid.Columns[5];
column5.HeaderText = "Description";
```

Comment: Sorry about that, this mistake is only there because I played with the code when I was trying to figure out what is wrong - but If I change what you suggested here, that doesn't make any difference anyway. But you said something about having columns in carsGrid - I don't have any prior to this initialization - do I have to set them in this Columns collection someplace else?¨

Comment: @Mythago ok np, can you please tell us that on which line you are getting exception.

Comment: Look at my edit - and my exception popped here:  DataGridViewColumn column0 = carsGrid.Columns[0];

Comment: So this means your `carsGrid` doesn't have any column. How are you adding column for `cardGrid`?

Comment: Well I thought that this adds all columns I want - but I am just learning this so, its probably wrong. Can you please briefly introduce me to the solution used for adding columns to datagrid?¨

Comment: @Mythago try to search on google that `how to bind the datagridview in c#?` you will get lot of examples and let us if any problem occur.

Comment: Well I can't get from it any solution how to add columns to the datagrid. I thought that this happens automatically when you bind the datasource to the grid, but it doesn't work